# Как сделать так, чтобы вывело все совпадения, а не первое попавшееся

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

```php
$query ="SELECT song_name FROM `songs` WHERE song_singer ='$song_singer'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query)
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row["song_name"];
```

Если вбивать sql запрос в консоли, то выводит 3 совпадения. Если сделать как выше, выведет первое попавшееся.

Comment: а в документации что написано на эту тему?

Comment: Так я поэтому и обратился сюда, что сижу битый час в непонимании.

Comment: Что значит сижу битый час в непонимании? Еще раз спрошу: "в **документации** что написано на эту тему?". Перефразирую: в документации что написано по поводу работы с `mysqli_fetch_assoc`? Или вы без документации работаете, наощупь? Этот ресурс - **не документация**

Comment: Спасибо. Я просто боялся что в SQL косяк, и искал все по нему. Все это время мне нужен был "mysqli_fetch_row".

Comment: рекомендую использовать все же `mysqli_fetch_assoc` чтобы обращаться как к ассоциативному массиву, а не по индексам

Comment: Блин, спасибо, мои действия были глупы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   echo $row["song_name"];
}
```

[примеры по работе с MySQL](http://www.khtulhu.org.ua/veb-programmirovanie/196-tri-sposoba-vyborki-iz-mysql.html)